Does a double-thickness block wall with no cavity require wall ties? (UK)
I'm just about to start blockwork on a self-build garage extension. The walls are 2 rows of standard 7n blocks with no cavity between them. If there is no cavity, do they still need to have wall ties to tie the two courses together or is the mortar be enough?
